# Call both javascript and php onload

Tags: javascript, onload

Another noob question. I have a wordpress theme that has this code in the header.php:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

I want to also call a javascript onload but not sure how to incorporate. I tried to stack them but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: you know javascript is added in the script tag right?

Comment: Define "stack them".

Comment: <body <?php body_class();?>;  hide_totals();>

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `onload='YourJavascriptFunction"` in your body tag.

If you are using jQuery, the `$(document).ready(function(){....});` should also work.

Comment: Can I do that alongside the php body_class call?

Comment: @chooseamc <body onload="hide_totals();" <?php body_class();?>>  Have you tried it like this?